# Fatal error while installing nltk

Tags: python, installation, nltk, fatal-error, qgis

I have been trying to install nltk on my machine. I have QGIS 2.2, 64 and windows7 64. I tried ez_setup, setuptools and pip... Finally I manage to install pip using [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html). however, now when I want to install nltk in cmd, it returns the following error:

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ' ""C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\bin\python.exe"" "C\python27\Scripts\pip.exe" install nltk'

whereas the qgis is installed in C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\python.exe.
I have changed all my setting to 64 for incompatibility reason with other packages. Now I can't install nltk. I know that nltk will finally copy 32-bit libraries but at least the installer is for 64-bit.

Any idea?! 
@Lukas Graf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help but I have often just downloaded the binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (his page provides 32- and 64-bit Windows binaries of many scientific open-source extension packages for the official CPython distribution of the Python programming language).

Comment: Worth noting that you need to download the yaml as its dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command on `cmd`, `pip install --user -U nltk`